How to solve this PDE with Lagrange's method
Consider the quasi-linear PDE
$$x^2 u_x + y^2 u_y = axy, \text{ } a \neq 0.$$
I found a first integral of the characteristic system
$$\dot{x} = x^2,$$
$$\dot{y} = y^2,$$
$$\dot{u} = axy,$$
given by $\zeta_1(x, y, u) = \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{y}$. However, I cannot find the other first integral in order to apply Lagrange's method... Moreover, what if we have neighbourhoods of points with $x = 0$ or $y = 0$?

$$x^2 u_x + y^2 u_y = axy, \text{ } a \neq 0.$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = y^2,$$
$$\frac{du}{dt} = axy,$$
or equivalently :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{axy}=dt$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}$
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=c_1}$$
This is what you found.
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{axy}$ with $\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}-c_1$
$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{ax}\left(\frac{1}{x}-c_1 \right)$
$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{a}{1-c_1x}$
$$u+\frac{a}{c_1}\ln|1-c_1x|=c_2$$
$u+\frac{a}{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}}\ln|1-(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})x|=c_2$
$$\boxed{u+a\frac{xy}{y-x}\ln\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|=c_2}$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is explicitly :
$$\boxed{\boxed{u(x,y)=-a\frac{xy}{y-x}\ln\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|+F\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right)}}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (To be determined if some boundary conditions are specified).
